# Let S be the tetrahedron in $R^3$ with vertices at the vectors ....

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, linear-transformations, area, volume

Let S be the tetrahedron in $R^3$ with vertices at the vectors $0,e_1, e_2, e_3$ and let $S^l$ be the tetrahedron with vertices at vectors $0, v_1, v_2, v_3$

a) Describe a linear transformation that maps $S$ onto $S^l$

b) Find a formula for the volume of the tetrahedron $S^l$ using the fact that
{volume of S}=(1/3){area of base}{height}

I tried doing b) by myself and here is what i came up with, i need someone to check my work...

1) (1/3){area of base}{height}

2) (1/3){1/2 h * b}{$v_3$ - 0}

3) (h*b($v_3$ - 0))/6

4) (($v_2$ - 0)($v_1$ - 0)($v_3$ - 0))/6

5) ($v_2$ * $v_1$ * $v_3$)/6

did i make any errors?

Comment: It is enough to define a linear transformation on a basis. Since the vertices of $S$ are the standard basis vectors (and $0$), you can take your linear map to be the matrix whose columns are $v_1,v_2,v_3$.

Comment: **HINT**: Where must a linear transformation map $0$? And can it map a basis to any vectors you want it to?

Comment: Hint. A linear transformation is determined by what it does on basis vectors. Where does the standard basis go? It might be useful to think about this problem first in two dimensions. Map the triangle with vertices $0, e_1, e_2$ into the one with vertices $0, v_1, v_2$. See what happens to the area.

Comment: So would the transformation look something like this then? $T(0, e_1, e_2, e_3)  = (0, v_1, v_2, v_3)$

Comment: Not quite. You're looking for a plain old ordinary linear transformation. The kind you've studied, the kind that has a matrix. Each such transformation acts on one vector at at time. For every linear transformation $T(0) = 0$.